# Tensor product anticommutative?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

The tensor product is anticommutative? I mean, is the following true?
$$A B dt\otimes dr=-A B dr\otimes dt$$ with $A$ and $B$  smooth functions.

My doubt comes out for the fact that if I have $(Adt+Bdr)\otimes (Adt+Bdr)=A^2dt\otimes dt+B^2dr\otimes dr+ABdt\otimes dr+ABdr\otimes dt$

Can I cancel the cross products each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't call the tensor product a "cross product", as that will inevitably be very confusing. Secondly, no, the tensor product is not anticommutative in general. In fact, the tensor product is defined as being "only bilinear and associative". It is the most general algebra of the kind (you generate a tensor algebra by giving a vector space to a so-called "free functor" that turns it into a tensor algebra in a standard way).

There are interesting algebraic quotients of the tensor algebra (doing an algebraic quotient is like injecting a property into another space using equivalence classes); one of which IS anticommutative for the tensor product (then called the exterior, or outer, product), called the exterior algebra.

However, your example looks like an exterior algebra example (often used for integration), so you might be in a context where you have an anticommutative outer product rather than a tensor product.